# Nested Overloading of '<<' within Multiple Typedefs

Tags: c++, overloading

This code compiles and runs in CLion 1.2.4, however the GUI is indicating errors (via red underline) with the output nesting involving `std::ostream`, noted below. This is meant to work with `std:cout`, and it does so far.

`Point` is a point (a vector) in k-dimenional space.

`Cluster` is a set of these points (a linked list).

`Clusters` is a set of clusters (a vector).

When I replace the typedefs with the parent class (`std::vector<double>` for `Point`) the indicated error persists.

Is there rationale for this error being misreported?

```
typedef std::vector<double>Point;
typedef std::list<Point>Cluster;
typedef std::vector<Cluster>Clusters;

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Point& v) {
    if ( !v.empty() ) {
        os << v[0];
        for(ctr_type i = 1; i < v.size(); ++i)
            os << ", " << v[i];
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Cluster& v) {
    if ( !v.empty() ) {
        for(Cluster::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
            os << "\n";
            os << *iter;   // Error: Binary operator '<<' can't be applied to the expressions of type 'ostream' and 'Point'
        }
    }
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, Clusters& v) {
    if ( !v.empty() ) {
        for(Clusters::iterator iter = v.begin(); iter != v.end(); iter++) {
            os << *iter;   // Error: Binary operator '<<' can't be applied to the expressions of type 'ostream' and 'Cluster'
        }
    }
    return os;
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding screenshots as requested by [Quuxplusone](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16369/quuxplusone).

[image]

[image]

Additionally, the majority of the bug reports surrounding this issue appear to revolve around strings.

Comment: This question would be better if you included an image of the red underline in question (and error message if any), and also included some evidence that you'd searched the CLion bug database already (or filed a bug). The actual answer might be as simple as the text of the error message: e.g., "you're not allowed to overload `operator<<` for library types in the `std` namespace", or "the RHS parameter should be const-qualified", or whatever.

Comment: Ahh - was attempting for brevity. My apologies. I thought indicating in the code as well as a screenshot might've been overkill...

Comment: Migrated from Code Review because this is not seeking open-ended critique. Rather, it is asking for an explanation or fix for a specific issue.

Comment: For one thing, as @Quuxplusone hinted at, the `Point`/`Cluster`/`Clusters` should be passed by `const` reference. Not the problem you're asking about, but good practice.

Comment: Agreed, however const and iterators don't appear to play well together...

Comment: They do, you might have made a different mistake in that case

Comment: The "different mistake in that case", @Miller, is that you need use e.g. `Cluster::const_iterator` to iterate over a `const Cluster`. Alternatively, stop typing out the names of your iterator types and just use C++11 `auto`, if that's an option; then the problem goes away entirely. (Or even use a C++11 ranged-for-loop, so you don't have to deal with iterators of *any* type, not even `auto`.)  This is completely tangential to the CLion bug, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in CLion:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-6013

Hopefully it will be fixed in the near future.